# How to convert DataFrame with Dictionary Values into other DataFrame, keys as column header

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe like below:

```
     "Unnamed: 0"
   0 {1:'Apple1', 2:'LemonA', 3:'StrawberryX'}
   1 {1:'Apple2', 2:'LemonB', 3:'StrawberryW'}
   2 {1:'Apple3', 2:'LemonC', 3:'StrawberryZ'}]
```

so myDf is DataFrame with 3*1 (3 rows and 1 column)
What is the best way to modify it like below:

```
        1         2          3
   0 'Apple1' 'LemonA' 'StrawberryX'
   1 'Apple2' 'LemonB' 'StrawberryW'
   2 'Apple3' 'LemonC' 'StrawberryZ'
```

After modification my new data shape is 3*3

Comment: Can you post `df.to_dict()` to the question?

Comment: thanks, that's really helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a series you can do

`pd.DataFrame(list(df['"Unnamed: 0"']))`

```
        1       2            3
0  Apple1  LemonA  StrawberryX
1  Apple2  LemonB  StrawberryW
2  Apple3  LemonC  StrawberryZ
```

Comment: `list` is a function while `[df[...]]` is treated as an array of 1 element

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for everyone who helped,
I've just figure-out the answer to my own question

This is how I solve it,

1. I convert all data on all rows into dictionary using pandas.DataFrame().to_dict() and save it on variable x
2. Then I run the following code

   newDf = pandas.DataFrame(x)

pandas is smart enough to read dictionary keys as column. :)

Answer (score -1):

> > > d = {1: ['Apple1', 'Apple2', 'Apple3'], 2: ['LemonA', 'LemonB', 'LemonC'], 3: ['StrawberryX', 'StrawberryY', 'StrawberryZ']}
> > > df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
> > > df
> > > 1       2            3
> > > 0  Apple1  LemonA  StrawberryX
> > > 1  Apple2  LemonB  StrawberryY
> > > 2  Apple3  LemonC  StrawberryZ

that would be the classic solution (you can skip putting the dictionery in the variable "d" and just write data={the data}, it just looks nicer)